# Regular Expression, pattern matching in xsd

Tags: regex

I was wondering how to make a regular expression for any character except `*` and `+` . I've tried `([^*+])` and `(\[^*+])` but both expressions seem to be incorrect. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Edit: Here is a code snipet. I've attached the reg ex suggested below into visual studio and it still generates an error when i enter in a regular string.

```
<xsd:element name="elementName">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="/^[^*+]+$/"></xsd:pattern>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Edit: The example string I'm using is "test" 
The result is pattern constraint fail with the current reg ex: `/^[^*+]+$/`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the [XML Schema regex flavor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html), you must not add regex delimiters (i.e., the `/` at either end of `/^[^*+]+$/`).  You also don't need to use anchors (i.e., the `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end); all regex matches are automatically anchored at both ends.  That line should read:

```
<xsd:pattern value="[^*+]+"></xsd:pattern>
```

...meaning the whole element must consist of one or more of any characters except `*` and `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the entire string. But you don't actually have to escape it in the character class:

```
/^[^*+]+$/
```

Comment: I'm still getting a pattern constraint fail when I attempt to input that pattern. <xsd:pattern value="/^[^*+]+$/"></xsd:pattern>

Comment: I'm not familiar with visual studio. You may need to remove the beginning and trailing `/` characters

Comment: Great! that works. Can you explain the meaning of the dollar sign at the end of the statement?

Comment: It matches the end of a string.

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the slashes.  You don't need the anchors either (`^` and `$`), but the XSL processor may just ignore those.

Answer (score -1):

You were close:

```
[^*+]
```

[image]

Notice that there's no need for escaping those characters inside square brackets, because they have no special meaning there.

**EDIT**: according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html:

> Note that the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (), the caret (^) and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character class, but doing so significantly 
>   reduces readability.

So the problem is not in the character escaping. Maybe you need to match *all* those occurences. In that case, look up @Cfreak's answer.

Comment: Your answer is listed as one of the things he tried ... ... are you certain they mustn't be escaped?  Seems odd that he claims to have tried it already.

Comment: @g.d.d.c maybe that's not true for all regex engines.. maybe he could try and give us the whole code sample where he tried it.

Comment: @Gabi - The problem is you need to test the entire string. As is it will only test the first character. See my answer. Maybe your tool does it by default, most programming languages do not.

Comment: I've attached a code snippet to the original question. Am I doing something incorrectly? If I take out the pattern match, it produces no error when i input a regular string...otherwise the reg ex doesn't seem to work for me. Thanks!

Comment: @g.d.d.c: you don't have to escape them in the expression, but you may need to escape them in your code so that the regular expression sees the appropriate un-escaped values, depending on how you define the regular expression.

Comment: Cfreak is right: your regex (`[^*+]`) only matches one character.  But you've also specified the "global" option in [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), which is why almost everything is being highlighted.  There is no such option in the XML Schema regex flavor, nor any need for it.