# Move an xml file within a SQL script depending on results

Tags: xml, redhat

I'm looking for a way to move some files depending on the outcome of a query to a 'rejected' directory on RedHat Linux. The database is Oracle 11gr2.

All four files are being processed in one go. They're being placed on a share by an FTP process and a scheduled OEM job checks for the existence of the XML files every 15 minutes.

When it sees that there are XML files to process, it picks them up, validates them with xmllint and copies the files to a working directory.

From there, the files are loaded into an external table depending on the outcome of the `WHERE` clause inside the query.

Does moving the file(s) to the `rejected` folder when they fail or when they contain one bad record need to happen during the loading process?

I've got 4 XML files in my test case:

- 1 is correct.

  - *Loaded without issues.*
- 1 has one bad and one good record

  - *The correct record is properly loaded and the false record isn't. But I'd like the whole 'bad' file to not be loaded and after not loading it in oracle, I'd like to move the file to a 'rejected' folder.*
- 1 has an XML error

  - *Correctly rejected by xmllint and moved to a 'rejected' folder.*
- 1 misses a value inside a tag.

  - *Rejected because it doesn't meet the compulsory values.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your files are being validated so it's not clear to me what is still missing.

Comment: Hi Wimbo, well, the testcase is that if the contents of a file don't match my query, e.g. last two digits of build year don't match the last two digits of the serialnumber, then the file should be moved to a rejected folder. So, it could very well be possible that an xml file is validated but is still not good enough for importing into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Validation of an XML file against an XSD or DTD can include regex expressions. Since your XSD/DTD will be read into memory at runtime, you can inject the actual regex as needed in order for your testcase to complete its work.

Have a look at e.g. [Regular Expression, pattern matching in xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819370/regular-expression-pattern-matching-in-xsd) for more info.