# Add pattern to anyURI data type in xsd

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

How can I guarantee that the url element starts with "http://"?

```
<xs:element name="url" type="xs:anyURI"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a `xs:restriction` for a Regular Expression using `xs:pattern`:

```
<xs:element name="url">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI">
            <xs:pattern value="http://.+" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

This will match to anything that starts with `http://`. It **will** match:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://somethingsomethingsomething
http://123456789!!!!!
http://0
```

It will **not** match `https` URLs:

```
https://github.com
```

If you want to match `https` as well you can change the pattern to

```
https?://.+
```

which means that the `s` is allowed and is optional.

If you want to match only valid URLs then you need to improve it to check for characters, followed by a dot, more characters, a valid domain suffix, etc. If you search for URL validation via regex you will find several examples. You can also try [this resource](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex). And to experiment with Regex, [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/) is a great resource.

Pattern matching in XSD has some restrictions. Check this [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819370/regular-expression-pattern-matching-in-xsd) which discusses that.